# SQL Server replication service in Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, replication, aws

I have a local infrastructure with multiple SQL Servers. Some of the servers have replications services to copy some data to a master database. Is it possible to have the replication services to work on a RDS SQL Server instance? Or do I need to have a EC2 instance with SQL Server and configure the service by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server RDS, you have DBO access to your databases and the ability to schedule jobs, but that is about it.  Amazon is now your DBA.  Restoring or renaming databases, setting up replication, etc. is restricted.

Comment: Fast forward to 2017, RDS now allows you to backup your database to an S3 bucket.  You can restore into RDS as well.  This is a HUGE win.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer in the Amazon documentation. The replication feature is currently not supported.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

Comment: I'm wondering though, is it possible to stand up an EC2 instance that can perform transactional replication as a publisher/distributor to an RDS subscriber?  Has anyone tried this?

Comment: `You can use CDC and AWS Database Migration Service to enable ongoing replication from SQL Server DB instances. ` from the same link.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Amazon Database Migration Service.  https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

As per the FAQ's:

Q. In addition to one-time data migration, can I use AWS Database Migration Service for continuous data replication?

Yes, you can use AWS Database Migration Service for both one-time data migration into RDS and EC2-based databases as well as for continuous data replication. AWS Database Migration Service will capture changes on the source database and apply them in a transactionally-consistent way to the target. Continuous replication can be done from your data center to the databases in AWS or in the reverse, replicating to a database in your datacenter from a database in AWS. Ongoing continuous replication can also be done between homogenous or heterogeneous databases. For ongoing replication it would be preferable to use Multi-AZ for high-availability.

Answer (score 1):

RDS is very restrictive. Many of the vanilla SQL Server standard features are not available on RDS. But you can use the Cloudbasic tool on the AWS Marketplace to replicate RDS. It works even for RDS SQL Web Edition.

[https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OU0PE5M/ref=_ptnr_blg_’blg2’](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OU0PE5M/ref=_ptnr_blg_%E2%80%99blg2%E2%80%99)